# How to use ImmutableList<> instead of List<> in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, immutable-collections, immutablelist

In my project, we are using either Entity Framework 6 and the Microsoft's System.Collections.Immutable types nuget package.

We aim to be able to do a query into the Database with EF and the data returned be immutable by default.

Since we have `one-to-many` relations, in EF we use a `List<>` type to represent that in our structure. But since we want it to be immutable and with strong guarantees, we want to use `ImmutableList<>` instead.

Just changing the table class property from `List<>` to `ImmutableList<>` doesn't seems to work, since the new migration will ignore the `ImmutableList<>` and remove the one-to-many relation we had before.

So, my question is if there is some way to make EF work with the `ImmutableList<>` type and if not, what are other alternatives to make this EF table structure immutable?

Comment: since EF, as an ORM, has to be able to alter data, I would say that you should encapsulate EF's DbSets and write a custom query method, which will return immutable Lists and establish that as the only way to query for data. Alternatively, you can make the setter of the navigation properties you require to be immutable to be private.

Comment: What's the underlying problem you're trying to tackle? Also, note that if you use immutable lists the entities it contains aren't necessarily immutable. My first impression is that you shouldn't expose entity types at all, but DTOs.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro and Gert Arnold thanks for the sugestions, it seems that DTOs is the way to go, I will try to use to automapper library to map the data to a Immutable DTO. So if one of you can send your messages as answers, I can mark it as such.

Comment: I guess this is an old and solved question? But it's what I get when I tried to search for how to use an ImmutableList<> in an OwnsMany situation in EF Core. I gave up and did it the old fashioned way:
`private readonly List<MyEntity> _foo;`
`public IReadOnlyList<MyEntity> Foo => _foo.AsReadOnly();` `ownednavigationbuilderforMyEntity.UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);`